# How to test container running in docker-compose on gitlab

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have an application that runs in docker.  For acceptance testing, I use docker-compose (this let's developers reproduce the environment locally, including the database).  These acceptance tests require the base url (or analogous ip) of a (containerized) webservice running in docker-compose.  I have been able to successfully run the application and the acceptance tests locally.  In order to do this, I found the base url/ip three different ways:
1 - use localhost
2 - use docker inspect
3 - assign a static ip (via networks) in docker compose

However, none of these approaches seem to work on gitlab ci.  Can someone please help me find the url/ip of the container (running in docker-compose on gitlab ci) so I can use it to test?

*Side Notes*

- Repo link: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension (on branch: 9-list-all-assessments)
- Docker-compose link: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/9-list-all-assessments/reading-comprehension-server-quarkus-impl/infrastructure/docker-compose.yml
- gitlab-ci file: https://gitlab.com/connorbutch/reading-comprehension/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml
- **The application (and acceptance tests) work locally, feel free to clone it and use the run it script to verify**
- **Before I needed a database, the url of the container running in gitlab was 'docker', but that doesn't work in docker-compose**